# Main layout doesn't catch onTouchListener when I swipe over nested widget

Tags: android

I have implemented for my layout onTouchListener like

```
        layout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                gdt.onTouchEvent(event);
                return true;
            }
        });
```

where I call SimpleOnGestureListener onFling. Problem is that I have inside layout other widgets and I cannot catch with this when you swipe over that widgets. I am trying to implement swipe changing but this main layout doesn't catch when I swipe over big nested widget inside(multiselect list). What to do ?

Answer (score 0):

make your activity implements onGestureListner.now override onFling() method and write necessary code suiting your cause.now set view's on gesture listner as view.onGestureListner(this) (assuming gdt is GestureDetector)
hope this help.

update:
if you are trying to implement detecting fling over a particular view try setting onTouchListner you wrote above to that view instead of layout and do the same for onGestureListner

Comment: I tried like you suggested but then I cannoy click on list ( single select list doesn't catch that event for choosing whe I put on touch adn I don't have enough info to call performItemClick)